# Algorithm to calculate a date for complex occupation management

Tags: algorithm, date

**Hello fellow Stack Overflowers,**

I have a situation, where I need some help choosing the best way to make an algorithm work, the objective is to manage the occupation of a resource (Lets consider the resource A) to have multiple tasks, and where each task takes a specified amount of time to complete. At this first stage I don't want to involve multiple variables, so lets keep it the simple way, lets consider he only has a schedule of the working days.

**For example:**

1 - We have 1 resource, resource A

2 - Resource A works from 8 am to 4 pm, monday to friday, to keep it simple by now, he doesn't have lunch for now, so, 8 hours of work a day.

3 - Resource A has 5 tasks to complete, to avoid complexity at this level, lets supose each one will take exactly 10 hours to complete.

4 - Resource A will start working on this tasks at 2018-05-16 exactly at 2 pm.

**Problem:**
Now, all I need to know is the correct finish date for all the 5 tasks, but considering all the previous limitations.

In this case, he has 6 working days and additionaly 2 hours of the 7th day.
The expected result that I want would be: 2018-05-24 (at 4 pm).

**Implementation:**
I thought about 2 options, and would like to have feedback on this options, or other options that I might not be considering.

**Algorithm 1**

1 - Create a list of "slots", where each "slot" would represent 1 hour, for x days.

2 - Cross this list of slots with the hour schedule of the resource, to remove all the slots where the resource isn't here. This would return a list with the slots that he can actually work.

3 - Occupy the remaining slots with the tasks that I have for him.

4 - Finnaly, check the date/hour of the last occupied slot.

**Disadvantage:** I think this might be an overkill solution, considering that I don't want to consider his occupation for the future, all I want is to know when will the tasks be completed.

**Algorithm 2**

1 - Add the task hours (50 hours) to the starting date, getting the expectedFinishDate. (Would get expectedFinishDate = 2018-05-18 (at 4 pm))

2 - Cross the hours, between starting date and expectedFinishDate with the schedule, to get the quantity of hours that he won't work. (would basically get the unavailable hours, 16 hours a day, would result in remainingHoursForCalc = 32 hours).

3 - calculate new expectedFinishDate with the unavailable hours, would add this 32 hours to the previous 2018-05-18 (at 4 pm).

4 - Repeat point 2 and 3 with new expectedFinishDate untill remainingHoursForCalc = 0.

**Disadvantage:** This would result in a recursive method or in a very weird while loop, again, I think this might be overkill for calculation of a simple date.

**What would you suggest? Is there any other option that I might not be considering that would make this simpler? Or you think there is a way to improve any of this 2 algorithms to make it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved version:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

    Date d=new Date();
    System.out.println(d);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    d.setHours(13);


    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);

    //c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -24-5);
    d=c.getTime();
    //int workHours=11;
    int hoursArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5, 10,11,12, 19,20, 40};
    for(int workHours : hoursArray)
    {
        try
        {
            Date end=getEndOfTask(d, workHours);
            System.out.println("a task starting at "+d+" and lasting "+workHours
                + " hours will end at " +end);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public static Date getEndOfTask(Date startOfTask, int workingHours) throws Exception
{
    int totalHours=0;//including non-working hours
    //startOfTask +totalHours =endOfTask
    int startHour=startOfTask.getHours();
    if(startHour<8 || startHour>16)
        throw new Exception("a task cannot start outside the working hours interval");
    System.out.println("startHour="+startHour);
    int startDayOfWeek=startOfTask.getDay();//start date's day of week; Wednesday=3
    System.out.println("startDayOfWeek="+startDayOfWeek);
    if(startDayOfWeek==6 || startDayOfWeek==0)
        throw new Exception("a task cannot start on Saturdays on Sundays");
    int remainingHoursUntilDayEnd=16-startHour;
    System.out.println("remainingHoursUntilDayEnd="+remainingHoursUntilDayEnd);
    /*some discussion here: if task starts at 12:30, we have 3h30min 
     * until the end of the program; however, getHours() will return 12, which
     * substracted from 16 will give 4h. It will work fine if task starts at 12:00,
     * or, generally, at the begining of the hour; let's assume a task will start at HH:00*/
    int remainingDaysUntilWeekEnd=5-startDayOfWeek;
    System.out.println("remainingDaysUntilWeekEnd="+remainingDaysUntilWeekEnd);
    int completeWorkDays = (workingHours-remainingHoursUntilDayEnd)/8;
    System.out.println("completeWorkDays="+completeWorkDays);
    //excluding both the start day, and the end day, if they are not fully occupied by the task
    int workingHoursLastDay=(workingHours-remainingHoursUntilDayEnd)%8;
    System.out.println("workingHoursLastDay="+workingHoursLastDay);
    /* workingHours=remainingHoursUntilDayEnd+(8*completeWorkDays)+workingHoursLastDay */

    int numberOfWeekends=(int)Math.ceil( (completeWorkDays-remainingDaysUntilWeekEnd)/5.0 );
    if((completeWorkDays-remainingDaysUntilWeekEnd)%5==0)
    {
        if(workingHoursLastDay>0)
        {
            numberOfWeekends++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("numberOfWeekends="+numberOfWeekends);

    totalHours+=(int)Math.min(remainingHoursUntilDayEnd, workingHours);//covers the case
    //when task lasts 1 or 2 hours, and we have maybe 4h until end of day; that's why i use Math.min

    if(completeWorkDays>0 || workingHoursLastDay>0)
    {
        totalHours+=8;//the hours of the current day between 16:00 and 24:00
        //it might be the case that completeWorkDays is 0, yet the task spans up to tommorrow
        //so we still have to add these 8h
    }
    if(completeWorkDays>0)//redundant if, because 24*0=0
    {           
        totalHours+=24*completeWorkDays;//for every 8 working h, we have a total of 24 h that have 
        //to be added to the date   
    }

    if(workingHoursLastDay>0)
    {
        totalHours+=8;//the hours between 00.00 AM and 8 AM
        totalHours+=workingHoursLastDay;
    }

    if(numberOfWeekends>0)
    {
        totalHours+=48*numberOfWeekends;//every weekend between start and end dates means two days
    }

    System.out.println("totalHours="+totalHours);

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startOfTask);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, totalHours);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
}
```

You may adjust the hoursArray[], or d.setHours along with c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, to test various start dates along with various task lengths.

There is still a bug , due to the addition of the 8 hours between 16:00 and 24:00:
*a task starting at Thu May 17 13:00:00 EEST 2018 and lasting 11 hours will end at Sat May 19 00:00:00 EEST 2018*.

I've kept a lot of print statements, they are useful for debugging purposes.

Here is the terminology explained:
[image]

Comment: even if you do not have Java installed, you can use an online editor such as https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler

Comment: fix: when doing Math.ceil( (completeWorkDays-remainingDaysUntilWeekEnd)/5 , replace /5 with /5.0 . Otherwise, instead of doing ceil (0.8), we do ceil(0)

Comment: also replace : totalHours+=remainingHoursUntilDayEnd;  with totalHours+=(int)Math.min(remainingHoursUntilDayEnd, workingHours);   , to cover the cases when the task lasts just 1 or 2 hours

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the ideas provided. I can't use it all because I have some other factors involved but this clearly helped a lot in my diagnostic and helped me getting there.

Comment: You’re not only using the long outmoded `Calendar` and `Date` classes, you are also using methods of the `Date` class that have been deprecated since Java 1.1, that must be for something like 20 years. I recommend you drop those classes and use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that algorithm 1 is overkill.

I think I would make sure I had the conditions right: hours per day (8), working days (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri). Would then divide the hours required (5 * 10 = 50) by the hours per day so I know a minimum of how many working days are needed (50 / 8 = 6). Slightly more advanced, divide by hours per week first (50 / 40 = 1 week). Count working days from the start date to get a first shot at the end date. There was probably a remainder from the division, so use this to determine whether the tasks can end on this day or run into the next working day.